# Numpy array with position

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 14 array with a shape (25,43). To all the arrays I pass a mask

```
max=np.ma.masked_where(_mascara<0.5,max)
min=np.ma.masked_where(_mascara<0.5,min)
```

This mask create nan positions, that I will like discard.

I will like save in txt a join array with the position in x(0 to 25) and y(0 to 43) and the value (that is 14 values) but eliminate the mased positions to free size.

Example:

x=0,y=12,max,min...tilt

If you dont mind help me.
Thank you and sorry my bad english.

CODE:

```
 m,n=np.mgrid[slice(0,25, 1),slice(0,43, 1)]


for x in variables:
    for y in dias:
        print y
        tmp=array(TODOS[y[0]:y[1],:,:,x])
        max=np.max(tmp,axis=0)
        max=np.ma.masked_where(_mascara<0.5,max)
        #max=np.ma.compressed(max)
        min=np.min(tmp,axis=0)
        min=np.ma.masked_where(_mascara<0.5,min)
        #min=np.ma.compressed(min)
        posicion=array(m)
        posicion=np.ma.masked_where(_mascara<0.5,m)
        #posicion=np.ma.compressed(posicion)

        print posicion.shape
        print max.shape
        print min.shape
        salida=array([m,max,min])
        np.savetxt('C:\\prueba_'+mapa[x]+'.csv',salida,delimiter=';')
```

I need (position,values) after this compresed and eliminate bad information

Comment: Have you considered something like ``ii = np.where(x>0.5)`` to obtain a list of indeces with the data you want and the generate a filtered array with ``x_new = x[ii]``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you can use [`MaskedArray.compressed](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.MaskedArray.compressed.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray.compressed), but for your specific requirements (to list the indices together with the data) you could do it all directly

```
>>> x = np.ma.array(100+np.arange(9), mask=[0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0]).reshape((3,3))

    masked_array(data =
    [[100 -- 102]
     [103 104 --]
     [-- -- 108]],
         mask =
    [[False  True False]
     [False False  True]
     [ True  True False]],
         fill_value = 999999)

>>> i = np.nonzero(~np.ma.getmask(x))   # get the indices of the unmasked items

    (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2]), array([0, 2, 0, 1, 2]))

>>> np.vstack((i, x[i]))  # build an array with the indices and elements together

    [[  0   0   1   1   2]
     [  0   2   0   1   2]
     [100 102 103 104 108]]
```

or, if you just want the paired indices as tuples you could use:

```
>>> zip(*i)

    [(0, 0), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
```

I'll leave it at this, without further edits.  With `i` and `x[i]` you can easily get anything you want (and if you want the masked items, just drop the `~` in the expression using `nonzero`).

Comment: Thank you for answer me.The problem is that I Lost the position x,y . I need have the postion to post the data after I need the position of the point (x,y) before compressed()

Comment: Thank you. The part of the mask I have clear the problem is save position before

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how this isn't what you're asking for.  Regardless, using the `np.nonzero` function you can get whatever indices you want: masked, unmasked, before, after, etc.  I think you're asking to save the indices of the elements before they were compressed, and that's what my method above does.

Comment: Thank you. My English sucks.
I Need before the value, its position in the array.example [[6,7],[8,9]] I need that save file 1 --> 0,0,6   file 2 -->0,1,7  file 3 -->1,0,8  file 4  -->  1,1,9

Comment: OK, I've taken another shot at this.  I hope this works for you.

Comment: This shoot go very well. If you dont mind it is posible the result [[0,0,100][0,0,102][1,0,103],[1,1,104],[2,2,108]] ;)) More thanks the code UP I go to work with this solution, but if you retouch a little to give the other solution. I find that if I call print np.vstack((i, x[i])) [:,0]... np.vstack((i, x[i])) [:,4] this give me the result [0,0,100]... [2,2,108].¿I clould create with np.vstack another array. Thank you , sorry my bad english

Comment: witih respect the mask, I load the mask of a archive _mascara=np.loadtxt('C:\\ndfd\\wgrib2\\mask.txt') after this masked with max=np.ma.masked_where(_mascara<0.5,max); It is the same that your mask?

Comment: First question: you can use `z = np.nonzero(~np.ma.getmask(x)).tranpose()`, then `z[2]` gives `[  1   0 103]`.  Second question: my `x` is similar to your `max` after `masked_where`, in that they are both masked arrays; but I don't really understand your question.  If you have another question, it would be better to make a new question on Stackoverflow rather than having and long discussion in the comments.